# Prevent Phonegap to slide (iFrames)

Tags: ios

I've a question.
I wrote a small app in Dreamweaver CS 5.5, to export it using Phonegap's SKD to an iOS app.
But the problem is: How can I prevent the user from moving the screen up and down when he slides with his fingers? I read on the Phonegap wiki that it is possible with DIV tags. But that won't work for me, because I use an index.html who reffers to frames. I don't use the the body. How can I prevent the user from slide the screen up and down?

index.html:

```
<html>
   <frameset cols="625,*" border=0 framespacing=0 frameborder="0">
      <frame src="frames/navbar.htm" scrolling=auto name="main">
      <frame src="frames/blank.htm" scrolling=auto>
  </frameset>
   </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this helpful web page?
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494815/Preventing-Scrolling-on-iPhone-Phonegap-Applications

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out iScroll http://cubiq.org/iscroll if you want the content under it to be scrollable with momentum.

Also disabling "touchmove" events will prevent any kind of movement from the user.
document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){event.preventDefault()});

iOS 5 gave us support for fixed elements and -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; but those don't give the best effect and can sometimes not work as expected.